# Avoid duplication in Django when having to format a message both in a template and as a response from an ajax call

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a chat board where people can post messages that can include attachments and some other additional things. When I retrieve all messages I loop over them and display each message in this way (simplified):

```
<p>Message posted by: <strong>{{ details.name }}</strong></p>
<p>{{ details.message }}</p>
<ul>
{% foreach attachment in attachments %}
<li>{{ attachment }}</li>
</ul>
{% endforeach %}
```

So far, so good. Now, my difficulty is that I use AJAX to allow people to post new message. Upon adding a new message, I struggle to find the best way to show this message to the user. The problem is that the new message needs to be formatted in a particular way (the above is a simplification; there are various conditions and additional formats). I can think of three ways:

- I use javascript to parse the message. That means I basically have the same code twice, in two different languages (once in Django's template language for all existing message, and then again in js for newly added messages)
- I craft the exact same HTML code in the view, so when I return a response through AJAX it already includes properly formatted code. However, this will also be a duplication of code - once in the template itself and again in the view
- I create a new function within the model that creates all the right HTML code (say formatMessage()). When I loop over existing messages, I can call this function, and when I add a new message I can call the same function and return this in my response.

The last option is the only one that does not have duplicated code. However, it would introduce a whole lot of code including HTML code to my modal, which seems like an awful thing to do.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason you can't use a template in an Ajax response. You can extract this template fragment into its own template file and either render it directly, in the case of the Ajax response, or include it in another template for a normal page view.

Comment: Great, thanks, I didn't think of this _very_ logical way of doing it!